# Hand in a list of the 4 PSNR values, and the rate-distortion curve

Tags: matlab, audio, signal-processing

I would like to draw the audio rate-distortion curve on matlab.
The result is not expected. Could anyone can help to point out the wrong step?

Expected result:

[image: Expected result]

My script result:

[image: My script result]

```
[x,fs] = audioread("speech.au");    %read audio
num = [7 4 2 1];    %quantized speech for 7, 4, 2 and 1 bit/sample
r = num*8;       %Assuming that the speech is sampled at 8kHz

PSNR = [];    %PY/PE
for i = 1 : length(num)
    m_q = Uquant(x,2^num(i)); %Uniform quantization
    error = (m_q - x);   %error signal E = m_q - x
    PY = 1/length(m_q) * sum(power(m_q,2));
    PE = 1/length(error) * sum(power(error,2));
    PSNR(i) = PY/PE;
end
dist = 1./ PSNR;
plot(r,dist,'-s');

xlabel("Bit Rate(Kbits/sec)");
ylabel("Distortion(1/PSNR)");
for i=1 : length(num)
    if i == 4
      text(r(i)-6,dist(i)+.05, num2str(dist(i)));
    else
      text(r(i)+1,dist(i)+.04,num2str(dist(i)));
    end
end
function [X, N] = Uquant(X,N);
d_x = double(X);
mx = max(d_x(:));
mi = min(d_x(:));
d0 = (mx - mi)/ (N-1);
z1 = round( (d_x-mi) ./ d0 );
X = z1 .* d0+mi; 
end
```

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. I've modified my question and added the result what I expected.

Comment: There are many different definitions for SNR and PSNR, are you sure you have the same definition as that was used for your expected output graph? Maybe a missing logarithm?